# It's showing error - Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: arrays, swift, error-handling

```
func solve(a: [Int], b: [Int]) -> [Int] {
    var aliceResult = 0;
    var bobResult = 0;

    for i in 0...3
    {
        if a[i] > b[i]
        {
            aliceResult += 1
        }

        if a[i] < b[i]
        {
            bobResult += 1
        }
    }
    let result = [aliceResult, bobResult]  // sample output = [1, 1]
    return result
}

var a = [5, 6, 7]
var b = [3, 6, 10]
solve(a: a, b: b)
```

It's showing index out of range as error

Comment: Your code has the (undocumented, non-obvious) precondition that `a` and `b` have `count` 4. You violated that precondition, and it crashed. This is a perfect first-hand learning experience about validating user input, documenting preconditions.

Comment: You should: 1) document/enforce the precondition, 2) rename `solve`, `a` and `b` to something meaningful, 3) return a tuple rather than an array, 4) use `let` where possible. Check out my implementation of this function: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/5486767c703faf24789514529b0346e0 Using `zip` to iterate two arrays at once really simplifies this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs from 0 to 3, so 4 times (0, 1, 2, 3).

Use:

```
for i in 0...2
```

According to the comments, you can try something like:

```
var aLength = a.count

for i in 0...aLength {
```

In this case you should use the `a` and `b` arrays with the same number of elements.

Comment: It runs 0 through 3, not 0 to 4.

Comment: ohh yes!! thank you so much !!!

Comment: @rmaddy Typo solved

Comment: You're welcome, I see you are new to SO, If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older SO which still don't have answers.

Comment: While this fixes the immediate issue, this is not really a good answer. You should not hardcode the range. It should be based on the actual size of the arrays passed into the function.

Comment: Yes, but the question is about why is the error.

Comment: yes I am new, to coding and stackoverflow. thank you @TamasSzoke

Comment: and I will keep that in mind @rmaddy. thanks to you too.